# How to get accept-language attrib with GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, httpclient

So, is there any way to read client's accept-language attribute with Google Appengine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On server side it's as simple as reading [requests headers](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getHeader%28java.lang.String%29):

```
String acceptLanguage = request.getHeader("Accept-Language");
```